# Create git branch without changing working copy

Tags: git

I just created a new repository and added a remote:

```
git init
git remote add foo something
```

Now I want git to be on the most recent commit of `foo/master`. Usually, that would just be:

```
git checkout master
```

Git is clever enough to use `foo/master` these days.

The challenge is that I already have files in my working copy and I don't want them to change. I want `git diff` to show me changes and I want to commit the local state and push it to foo.

Background: The local state is a generated website about to be pushed to Github Pages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have just done `git init` in a new repository (as opposed to re-`init`-ing an existing repository), and have not yet run `git commit`, you are currently on an *unborn branch* (normally `master`-as-unborn-branch).  What this means is that `HEAD` contains the *name* `master`, while the branch named `master` does not actually exist.

If you have furthermore not run any `git add` commands, your index is currently *empty*.

The state that you would *like* to have is to have the name `master` point to the same commit as `foo/master`, without changing the contents of the work-tree.  But first you need to obtain all the commits from remote `foo`:

```
$ git fetch foo
```

Now you can create the branch itself:

```
$ git branch master foo/master
```

Since you're already on `master`—it was merely "unborn"—you are now still on `master` and `master` points to the same commit as `foo/master`.

Your index is still empty, so `git status` will show you as having deleted every file from the `HEAD` commit, with every file in the work-tree as an untracked file.  If you would like to populate your index from the current commit, you can now do:

```
$ git read-tree HEAD
```

and then `git reset` various files to restore them.  If not—if you just want to use the work-tree—you can simply `git add .` (though you may want to set up a `.gitignore` first).